# Where does “work your ring off” come from?

Tags: etymology, idioms, slang, phrase-origin, australian-english

I’ve heard the expression “work your ring off” my whole life in Australia. It means (as I understand it), to work until exhaustion.

But trying to find the origin of the expression has come up empty; there’s very few results online.

Does anyone know how this phrase originated?

Answer (score 5):

*Ring* in this idiom is a euphemism for "arse" so the idiom is a variant of *to work one's arse off*. The earliest usage is from 1992 per *[Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/yznocli#vubgh7a)*:

> **work one’s ring off** (*v.*) [var. on *work one’s arse off* under work *v.*] 
> (*Aus.*) to work very hard.
>
> **1992**  [Aus]   R.G. Barrett *White Shoes* 6: Porking some bloke’s girl behind his back while the poor mug’s out working his ring off wasn’t actually cricket.

The slang *ring* meaning "arse" is from 1798 per *Green’s Dictionary of Slang*:

> 1. as a ‘circular’ part of the body. 
>    (b) the anus, the buttocks; thus *ring-snatcher*, a sodomite, *ring-snatching*, sodomy.
>
> **1798** [UK] ‘Cropt Comet’ in *Hilaria* 101: For I’ve been in the milky way, / And Saturn’s filthy ring, sir. 
> **1937–84** [UK]    Partridge *DSUE* (1984) 977/1: late C.19–20.